# Different font sizes on different PCs with same resolutions

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a WinForm desktop application.

I have installed it on 2 different client PCs.

On 1 PC the captions fit with their controls.
On the other the label does not resize properly.

I went to check the resolution on each Client PC expecting differences but on the resolution 1920x1080 it did not fit and on the resolution 1680x1050 it did fit.

To make things more weird on my development PC the resolution is 1920x1080 and yes the labels do fit.

AutoSize on Form and label is 'true'.

What am I missing?

[image: Clients PC at 1920x1080]

[image: My Development PC]

Comment: Not sure but this seems to be related to  http://www.ehow.com/how_5949822_enlarge-fonts-windows.html

Comment: HI, yes you were right. Thanks. Solved the mystery.  Just need a programming solution as the User wants to use their font settings :(

Comment: @HansPassant HI, thanks for that. So the only setting I can see is the AutoScaleMode on the Form Control. I assume meant that?

Comment: Hmm, I did have it set to DPI originally. So what property of label lets me imhherit from from font?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On the other the label does not resize properly

No, it is the *exact* opposite.  It did resize properly, leaving enough space for the text.  Problem is, the text is too wide.

There is more than one problem going on here.  Starting point is that the other machine is operating at a different DPI setting.  Dots-per-inch, it determines how a font size of, say, 10 points is mapped to pixels on the screen.  You have a nice monitor, a high resolution one at 1920 x 1080 pixels.  To keep text readable, you wanted 10 points to take more pixels.  So you increased the DPI setting.  Very easy to do on later Windows versions, you probably moved to slider to 125%.  Effective DPI is 120 dots per inch.

Your program however is running on an older machine, one that still has the legacy setting (100% = 96 dpi).  This tends to cause accidents, you avoided the most common ones given that the form properly rescaled itself.  It shrunk itself to match the lower DPI setting.  The layout is still correct, the labels and textboxes have the correct size and location.

But you can see a mishap with the bitmap, it is now too big too fit the space.  Not the most obnoxious side-effect here.  Otherwise not that easy to fix, to see the entire bitmap it has to be shrunk as well and that causes it to get fuzzy and lose detail.  The only perfectly clean fix is to have *two* bitmaps, each drawn to match the dpi of the target machine.  Unfun and often skipped.

Moving to the problem you are complaining about, text rendering at different dpi setting can be a problem as well.  At issue is that the *height* of text scales quite well, but the *width* does not.  The technical term for that is that text rendering is not resolution independent.  The chief issue is pixel-grid fitting, a technique used to make text more readable at low monitor resolutions.  Aided by TrueType hinting, the shape of a letter is stretched so that stems of a character fall exactly on a monitor pixel.  Which greatly improves readability, but of course the side effect is that text will be wider on such low resolution monitors.

But your text is off so much that another explanation is needed.  The most likely mishap here is that you used a font that is not available on the old machine.  The operating system now must fallback to a substitute font and it has a very different pitch from your original font.  I can't see your code but I'd roughly guess at a mapping from Segoe to Microsoft Sans Serif.

There are no simple solutions to these kind of problems, it is just something you need to be aware of.  A basic guideline is that it is almost never a problem to scale up, scaling down is a lot more troublesome.  So running your dev machine at 96 dpi is in general a good idea, other than the inconvenience of course.  Testing on older operating systems, or putting your foot down with a strongly stated prerequisite (like XP not supported), is required.  Demanding a higher resolution than 96 dpi is however still unreasonable, lots of machines are still at that legacy setting.  Not in the least because changing it causes so many programs to misbehave.  96 dpi has been the default setting for *way* too long, those days are however over and done with.

Comment: HI, thanks for such a comprehensive reply.   I realised the font may have not been available so I switched to a system font Microsoft Sans Serif.  The DPI on client PC was 125%. The one on my dev PC is 100%.  If switch to 100% on client PC then all is fine. But, I still have the problem of targeting PCs with different DPI.  :(

Comment: Sigh, another unsubtle reminder that I should never debug code from screenshots.

Comment: lol. You were right nitially that it was not a system font which I changed. I just did not update the sreenshots and I should of (apologies). This is new to me these issues so sorry f I was not comprehensive enough in my question. I thought your explanation and possible causes were excellent by the way. i would have (and may still do so) accept your answer I am just hoping someone could propose a solution. Like you said it is not easy.,